# apache .htacces - rewrite to url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on simple php site that have two subsites: leasing.php and article.php.

I want to user see this subsites like this:
http://domain/leasing  (show leasing.php) - this works fine
http://domain/leasing/article-name (show article.php?alias=$variable) - this not

my .htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(/$|$) index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^leasing leasing.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^leasing/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ article.php?alias=$1 [NC,L]
```

How to change RewriteRules to see article.php page in browser?

Comment: LazyLizzard if one of the answers helped you, please select it (and upvote if you wish). It takes time to research, test and write up these answers. Not very cool to ask & run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^leasing$           leasing.php [NC,END]
RewriteRule ^leasing/(.*)/?$    article.php?alias=$1 [NC,END]
```

You ran into trouble because since both of your rules are matched by the path `/leasing/article-name`, and because url rewriting happens on a first come first served basis, the parser never even looked at your last rule.

The fix is to alter the first rule so that although it matches `/leasing`, it no longer matches `/leasing/article-name`.  The simplest way to do this is to end the pattern with `$` immediately after leasing.  Any path that goes on after that will no longer match the first rule.

The flags I use are slightly different from yours. Whereas you have `L`, I use `END`.  The difference is subtle, but basically if you know this is the last rewrite you need for this path (final destination), use `END`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I thought it would be superfluous because @dragoste does a good job of explaining what was wrong with the OP and his answer which is really close to mine. Perhaps you're right though.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the leasing.php's rewirte rule:

```
RewriteRule ^leasing leasing.php [NC,L]
```

The condition is `^leasing` which means "*everything that **starts** with `leasing`*". This matches also `leasing/article-name` url.

Add `$` (which stands for *end of the string*) sign at the end condition expression (`^leasing$`) to make it match only exactly `leasing` url and not the others.

```
RewriteRule ^leasing$ leasing.php [NC,L]
```